# Avoiding "Waiting for table metadata lock" when `ALTER TABLE DROP PARTITION`?

Tags: mysql, innodb, partitioning, locking, alter-table

I have some tables that many users need to access to:

```
mysql> show create table v3_cam_date\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: v3_cam_date
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `v3_cam_date` (
  `campaignid` mediumint(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `totalclick` mediumint(9) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `totalview` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `realclick` mediumint(9) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `clickcharge` mediumint(9) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `viewcharge` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `uv` mediumint(9) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `uc` mediumint(9) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `dt` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `ctr` decimal(5,3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000' COMMENT '=-1: meaning not available(N/A)',
  `moneyc` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `moneyv` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  KEY `ix_campaignid_dt` (`campaignid`,`dt`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(dt))
(PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (0) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p01 VALUES LESS THAN (734502) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (734683) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p03 VALUES LESS THAN (734863) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p04 VALUES LESS THAN (734959) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p5 VALUES LESS THAN (735141) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p06 VALUES LESS THAN (735210) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION MERGER_2013227 VALUES LESS THAN (735291) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION pcurrent_2013227 VALUES LESS THAN (735292) ENGINE = InnoDB) */
```

When an user want to drop a partition `ALTER TABLE v3_cam_date DROP PARTITION pcurrent_2013227`, it may cause many transactions to be in the `Waiting for table metadata lock` state:

```
     Id: 31560182
   User: alice
   Host: 192.168.3.40:36132
     db: db
Command: Query
   Time: 806
  State: Waiting for table metadata lock
   Info: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT A.`campaignid`)  INTO _campaigncomplete
        FROM `ox_campaigns` A 
        INNER JOIN `selfserving_users` B ON B.`user_id` = A.`uid`
        INNER JOIN `v3_cam_date` C ON C.`campaignid` = A.`campaignid`
        WHERE A.`revenue_type` = 5 AND A.`deleted` = 0 AND A.`expire` = DATE_ADD(    (SELECT `sys_date_cpc` FROM `000_sys_params_v4`) , INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
                AND A.`isExpired` = 0 AND IF( NAME_CONST('_permitid',3) = -1, 1=1, IF( NAME_CONST('_permitid',3) = 0, A.`uid` IN (SELECT C.`user_id` FROM `selfserving_users` C WHERE C.`groupid` =  NAME_CONST('_groupid',17) ) ,A.`uid` =  NAME_CONST('userid',5770)))
```

What is the efficient way to accomplish this without locking?

Answer (score 9):

What you are asking for is impossible. Regardless of storage engine, DDL of any kind will lock a table. If you must remove a partition from a table that is active, you should:

1. Setup MySQL Replication (if you haven't done so already)
2. Perform all SELECTs involving `v3_cam_date` against the Slave
3. `STOP SLAVE;` on the Slave
4. Perform `ALTER TABLE ... DROP PARTITION` on the Master.
5. Perform all SELECTs involving `v3_cam_date` against the Master
6. `START SLAVE;` on the Slave (Replicates `ALTER TABLE ... DROP PARTITION` to the Slave)

This is probably your only recourse. The only other recourse is to simply wait out the `ALTER TABLE ... DROP PARTITION`.

This situation requires some intervention in the application. Within your application, you would have to create a Write DBVIP on the Master and use the Read DBVIP with one of the following three(3) options:

## OPTION #1

- Keep the Read DBVIP on the Slave

## OPTION #2

- Keep the Read DBVIP on the Master
- When you must do an `ALTER TABLE`, move the Read DBVIP to the Slave
- When `ALTER TABLE` has been completed, move the Read DBVIP to the Master

## OPTION #3

- Setup Read DBVIP on a LoadBalancer
- Remove Master from LoadBalanced DBVIP on demand

Option #1 seems to be the simplest way in the long run.

Comment: The `ALTER` and the `SELECT` are executed from different users. How can we switch the reading from Slave to the Master, flexibility?

Comment: I see in the doc https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-limitations-locking.html that its possible to perform DDL queries without locking all the partitions.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid this kind of problem insure to commit or rollback your transaction.

due to SELECT  table is locked in shared mode.

Here is example

```
session1 > start transaction;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

session1 > select * from test order by id;
+----+------+
| id | a    |
+----+------+
|  1 | x  |
|  2 | y  |
+----+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

session2 > ALTER TABLE test add column c char(32) default 'xyz';

session3 > show processlist;
+----+----------+-----------+------+---------+------+---------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| Id | User     | Host      | db   | Command | Time | State                           | Info                                                        |
+----+----------+-----------+------+---------+------+---------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | sameer | localhost | test | Sleep   |  253|                                 | NULL                                                        |
|  2 | sameer | localhost | test | Query   |    3 | Waiting for table metadata lock | ALTER TABLE test add column c char(32) default 'xyz' |
|  3 | sameer | localhost | test | Query   |    0 | NULL                            | show processlist                                            |
+----+----------+-----------+------+---------+------+---------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)


session1 > rollback;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

session2 > ALTER TABLE test add column c char(32) default 'xyz';
Query OK, 2 rows affected (46.32 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

You can kill all sessions which are in sleep mode or exit session from where SELECT executed.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this answer more than once- it may not be a direct answer to the question, but the information helped me so much :)

Answer (score -1):

Another option is to swap tables perform the work then swap back.
Swapping table is very fast.

```
swap current table with a new one (alter table rename table1 to table1_tmp , table1_new to table1).
export data from table1_tmp
delete data from table1_tmp
add partition to table1_tmp
then alter table rename table1 to table1_new, table1_tmp to table1
insert into table1 select * from table1_new
truncate table table1_new
```

Answer (score -7):

I've solved this issue by just restarting the MySQL service, and then try to drop the partition. After this the drop partition will take effect. This happens because the binlog apparently has something that hasn't finished with that table.

I hope this information could be helpful for you.

Comment: I don't think this is what the person asking the question is about. quanta is asking for a solution that doesn't block (presumably so that the overall response time of his database stay good) - restarting the service will make it unavailable and fail all current transactions.